# Iteration on arrays

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to create sript to check pools statuses. Each of the pool will return scan result like below:

```
pool1 - scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:06:17 with 0 errors on Thu Sep 
pool2 - scan: scrub in progress since Thu Sep 
pool3 - scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:04:02 with 0 errors on Thu Sep 
pool4 - scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:04:22 with 0 errors on Thu Sep
```

I need to iterate on each of them and check if the scan is completed. And if all of them contain
***scrub repaired*** then do something. If there is one in progress or two, I need to check them lets say every 5 seconds and wait all of them to complete. So far I have this without the do/until loop:

```
declare -a scans=("pool1 - scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:06:17 with 0 errors on Thu Sep" 
"pool2 - scan: scrub in progress since Thu Sep"
"pool3 - scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:04:02 with 0 errors on Thu Sep" 
"pool4 - scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:04:22 with 0 errors on Thu Sep"

for scan in "${scans[@]}"; do
    echo "$scan"
    if ![[ $scan == *"scrub repaired"* ]]; then
            echo "Scan in progress. Waiting.."
    elif [[ $scan == *"scrub repaired"* ]]; then
            echo "Scan is ready. Saving it somewhere for documentation"
            
    else
            continue
    fi
    break
done
```

Comment: And is that working? Do you get any errors? You should at least get a syntax error if you try to run that.

Comment: And you are probably getting an error saying `bash: ![[: command not found`, right?

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ is a free and a useful tool for shell scripting. But also, I suppose you don't just want to loop over a fixed list of strings, but need to run some commands to get them. Is that the part you've already done and that works, or is that part of the question too?

Comment: Yes, the list is not fixed I need to run ***zpool status*** to get the scans, but this is not the problem. The code I posted is not working because I don't know at the moment how to iterate over each pool and if the scan is ready to skip it on next iteration and then just get the remaining one every 5 sec until it is done. When every scan is done I need to save them somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've had a couple of hours to research this a bit, so here is a non-optimized solution that does not depart too much from your original idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

declare -a scans=("pool1 - scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:06:17 with 0 errors on Thu Sep" "pool2 - scan: scrub in progress since Thu Sep" "pool3 - scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:04:02 with 0 errors on Thu Sep" "pool4 - scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:04:22 with 0 errors on Thu Sep")

pools_to_complete=${#scans[@]}
pools_completed=0

while ! [ "$pools_completed" == "$pools_to_complete" ]; do
    pools_completed=$(grep -c "scrub repaired" < <(for scan in "${scans[@]}"; do printf "%s\n" "$scan";done))

    if [ "$pools_completed" == "$pools_to_complete" ]; then
        printf "All %s scans are complete. Saving it somewhere for documentation\n" "$pools_to_complete"
    else
        printf "Scan in progress. Waiting...\n"
        sleep 5
    fi
done
```

You can do much better than the above. What I would primarily change in your approach is:

- avoid storing the sort of execution trace for each pool process (completed or not) in an Bash array. Arrays are practical but make shell scripts non portable.
- instead of an array, store each trace in an external file (`infile`), one trace to a line.

Replacing your array with an external file entails two simple modifications of the above:

- the two lines immediately following the "shebang" are replaced by just:
  `pools_to_complete=$(wc -l infile)`
- the first line inside the `while` block becomes just:
  `pools_completed=$(grep -c "scrub repaired" < infile)`

Note that all of the above supposes that there can only be 0 or 1 instance of the string "scrub repaired" per line in `infile` or per array component, if you stick to arrays. This is because `grep -c ...` counts the number of occurences of the searched pattern(s).   HTH